# React missing an onClick?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following code in a component:

```
  deleteShare: function(e) {
    console.dir(e);
  },

  render: function() {
    createShare = function(share) {
      return (
        <span key={share} className='share'>
          {share}
          <a href="#" onClick={this.deleteShare}>x</a>
        </span>
      )
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <input type='hidden' name='shares' value={this.state.shares.join(',')} />

        <div className='ticket_shares'>
          {this.state.shares.map(createShare)}
          <input type='text' id='new_share' placeholder='Add an email' onKeyDown={this.addShare}/>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
```

However, I'm finding that the onClick on a anchor in `createShare` doesn't appear to trigger, like it's not binding.  There's no error or anything in the console.

I assume there's something funky going on with the way React is setting up bindings to the event, or some sort of context issue.  How can I resolve this?

Comment: looks like you are missing a var keyword on createShare too

Comment: *"I assume there's something funky going on with the way React is setting up bindings to the event"* No, just normal JS behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `createShare` `this` will be bound to window, as it is inside the function.

You could change `createShare` to a method on the component, and React will [autobind it to the component](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/interactivity-and-dynamic-uis.html#under-the-hood-autobinding-and-event-delegation), or bind it to what you expect with [Function.prototype.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

Another nice solution is [ES6 arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) which bind `this` to the scope they are defined in, but that will take a bit of setup